# Instance Average CPU Utilization not displaying but everything else is?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

Currently I have a function that records the average CPUUtilization of a running Instance.
But the problem is this cloudwatch function even after having a time.sleep put within to give time for the Instance to start running while it configures the CPU Utilization is that it still doesn't display the Average CPU Utilization as shown below in the error message.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import boto3
import time
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'eu-west-1')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
keyname = 'key1.pem'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
user_data = '''#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl start httpd'''

try:
        resp = s3.create_bucket(ACL='private',Bucket='buket2',C$
        print (resp)
except Exception as error:
    print (error)

try:
        s3_resource.Bucket('buket2').upload_file('image.jpg', 'image$

try:
        gg = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='Server', Description = '$
        print (gg)
except Exception as error:
    print (error)

response = sg.authorize_ingress(
    IpPermissions=[
        {
            "FromPort": 22,
            "ToPort": 22,
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "IpRanges": [
                {"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "Description": "Server"},
            ],
        },
        {
            "FromPort": 80,
            "ToPort": 80,
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "IpRanges": [
                {"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "Description": "Server1"},
            ],
        },
    ],
)
instance = ec2.create_instances(
 ImageId='ami-03odd1b743b23e5d2',
 MinCount=1,
 MaxCount=1,
 InstanceType='t2.nano',
 KeyName = 'key1.pem',
 UserData = user_data, 
 SecurityGroupIds=[sg.group_id] 
)


from datetime import datetime, timedelta
time.sleep(390)
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
response = client.get_metric_statistics(
            Namespace='AWS/EC2',
            MetricName='CPUUtilization',
            Dimensions=[
                {
                'Name': 'AMIID',
                'Value': 'ami-03odd1b743b23e5d2'
                },
            ],
            StartTime=datetime(2021, 7, 17) - timedelta(seconds=300),
            EndTime=datetime(2021, 7, 17),
            Period=300,
            Statistics=[
                'Average',
            ],
            Unit='Percent'
        )
print(response)

for cpu in response['Datapoints']:
  print(cpu)
```

```
s3.Bucket(name='buket2')
ec2.SecurityGroup(id='sg-06b84927ae5rd3ad1')
{'Label': 'CPUUtilization', 'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'ba4352d5-67ee-4d51-b03f-d1c532dbfe7', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'ba421b45-63dd-4d51-b03f-d14212e2fe7', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '337', 'date': 'Sun, 18 Jul 2021 00:26:57 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
sg-06b84927ae5rd3ad1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Period` usually would be set to 5 minutes, unless you have enabled detailed monitoring for the instance. Then it can be set to 1 minute as well.

Your `StartTime` and `EndTime` is only 5 minute apart. There maybe no metric points in such a short time span.

Comment: The problem is that I have this function within my create_instance script so when I execute it I assume it will never have enough time to display the avg CPU Utilization since it's launching? Basically I am needing to monitor Instance metrics such as CPU utilisation using CloudWatch so when I execute the script I need it to also return the CPU Utilization % or number. How could I make this possible while keeping it automated?

Comment: @Decjk You have to introduce delay between create instances and checking metrics.

Comment: Is there documentation for this that I could try implement?

Comment: @Decjk time.sleep() for how many minutes you need for first metrics to show. At least 5 minutes with basic monitoring.

Comment: Yeah I had it on 6 minutes and the CPU Utilization kicked in at the 5 minute mark and finished executing the instance at the 6th minute, it still displayed the same message as in the post, it didn't add the additional "Average: " to it for some reason?

Comment: @Decjk I think it would be better if you posted actual code example that allows to reproduce your issue. Its difficult to speculate without seeing your code and what you are doing.

Comment: Sure, I attached to the post.

Comment: Any clue what could be wrong? Still not displaying