# EC2 Metric executes with no errors but doesn't display as it should

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

Currently I have a function that records the average CPUUtilization of a running Instance.

But the problem is this function is not displaying the Average value percentage for some reason even though it shows the same on https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html under `client.get_metric_statistics` so I am not sure if one of the values is wrong but it's the correct AMI set.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import boto3
import time
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'eu-west-1')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
keyname = 'key1.pem'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
user_data = '''#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl start httpd'''

try:
        resp = s3.create_bucket(ACL='private',Bucket='buket2',C$
        print (resp)
except Exception as error:
    print (error)

try:
        s3_resource.Bucket('buket2').upload_file('image.jpg', 'image$

try:
        gg = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='Server', Description = '$
        print (gg)
except Exception as error:
    print (error)

response = sg.authorize_ingress(
    IpPermissions=[
        {
            "FromPort": 22,
            "ToPort": 22,
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "IpRanges": [
                {"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "Description": "Server"},
            ],
        },
        {
            "FromPort": 80,
            "ToPort": 80,
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "IpRanges": [
                {"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "Description": "Server1"},
            ],
        },
    ],
)
instance = ec2.create_instances(
 ImageId='ami-03odd1b743b23e5d2',
 MinCount=1,
 MaxCount=1,
 InstanceType='t2.nano',
 KeyName = 'key1.pem',
 UserData = user_data, 
 SecurityGroupIds=[sg.group_id] 
)


from datetime import datetime, timedelta
time.sleep(390)
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
response = client.get_metric_statistics(
            Namespace='AWS/EC2',
            MetricName='CPUUtilization',
            Dimensions=[
                {
                'Name': 'AMIID',
                'Value': 'ami-03odd1b743b23e5d2'
                },
            ],
            StartTime=datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=300),
            EndTime=datetime.now(),
            Period=300,
            Statistics=[
                'Average',
            ],
            Unit='Percent'
        )
print(response)

for cpu in response['Datapoints']:
  print(cpu)
```

```
s3.Bucket(name='buket2')
ec2.SecurityGroup(id='sg-06b84927ae5rd3ad1')
{'Label': 'CPUUtilization', 'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'ba4352d5-67ee-4d51-b03f-d1c532dbfe7', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'ba421b45-63dd-4d51-b03f-d14212e2fe7', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '337', 'date': 'Sun, 18 Jul 2021 00:26:57 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
sg-06b84927ae5rd3ad1
```

Comment: I believe that your `time.sleep(390)` amount is too low while having a CPU metric datapoint available is more than 5 minutes. Usually, it should be at least 10 minutes to be safe. (Creation time and boot up time ~ 5 minutes already)

Comment: Yeah I thought that last night so I left it at 660 seconds which still didn't display anything so i'm pretty unsure what the issue is which is why I am here to ask. Will try with a longer time now.

Comment: Yeah this time I left it sleep for 700 seconds and still not displaying, thing is I see under 'Monitoring' that after 5-6 minutes it starts recording the metric so realistically it should be long enough?

Comment: Does you're code work? What do if you try to get metrics of old instances?

Comment: Also check your time zone. Metrics use utc, so maybe you keep requesting wrong time due to wrong timezone

Comment: Maybe the time zone could be the problem as I haven't changed since I set it up, not entirely sure what to put it as but today is the 18/07/2021 so should it be for both or? Sorry I don't understand this StartTime and EndTime very well.

Comment: Why this is same question as this but different user name? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416488/instance-average-cpu-utilization-not-displaying-but-everything-else-is/68417188?noredirect=1#comment120936678_68417188

Comment: Why have you instantly stopped replying once you seen it was from the other account you also stopped replying to randomly? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `StartTime=datetime(2021, 7, 17)` and `EndTime` are **in the past**. Any newly created instance will not have any past data. You can try with current timestamp:

```
StartTime=datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=300),
EndTime=datetime.now()
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that to the script since it works better but still no luck unfortunately, however I tried what you said of getting metric of a old instance which I did by leaving it active for 15minutes, it still doesn't display the "Average:" meaning it has to be the code, is there any way to maybe just display the current metric, maybe it will work better?

Comment: Why this is same question as this but different user name? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416488/instance-average-cpu-utilization-not-displaying-but-everything-else-is/68417188?noredirect=1#comment120936678_68417188

Comment: Would not allow me to post on previous so I created another to ask this 1 question. I have changed it to Maximum and it still doesn't display, I see on here https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html it shows the exact same as I have, any idea what could cause this?